# call data of one class in another class c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I’ve a class

```
public class GetRate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string StockName;
    private decimal? VolumeOrdered;
    private decimal? BuyRate;
    private decimal? SellRate;        
    private DateTime? OrderedDate;        
}
```

Another class which initializes it with a webservice.

```
private static void Parse(List<GetRate> rates, XDocument doc)
    {
        XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");

        foreach (GetRate getRate in rates)
        {                
     XElement q = results.Elements("rate").First(w=>w.Attribute"StockName").Value==rates.Symbol);

            rates. VolumeOrdered = GetDecimal(q.Element("VolumeOrdered").Value);
            rates. BuyRate = GetDecimal(q.Element("BuyRate").Value);
            rates. SellRate = GetDecimal(q.Element("SellRate").Value);
            rates.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Now I want use its value in another class. How it may possible?
I want use

```
 class ABC
 {
    VolumeOrdered* BuyRate;
     //Or
    VolumeOrdered* SellRate;
 }
```

Need help…
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Sorry That second is in another class suppose class ABC

Comment: make `BuyRate` and `SellRate` public in `GetRate`. Or better yet, use getters and setters.

Comment: This is really really basic. Have you read any book on c# ? Suggest you do some homework first

Comment: Is VolumeOrdered a member or a type??? The code in "another class" doesn't make much sense to me, you defined it as a member earlier and now you're using it as a type.

Comment: Into `foreach` loop you should use `getRate`. Not `rates`. And change fields into `GetRate` to `public`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make variables you want to access in other classes visible in other classes:

```
public class GetRate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string StockName;
    private decimal? VolumeOrdered;
    public decimal? BuyRate;
    public decimal? SellRate;        
    private DateTime? OrderedDate;        
}
```

Better yet, you should use getters and setters:

```
public class GetRate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string StockName;
    private decimal? VolumeOrdered;
    public decimal? BuyRate { get; set; }
    public decimal? SellRate { get; set; }        
    private DateTime? OrderedDate;        
}
```